# why i can't open my files?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\champion\Desktop\政大資料科學競賽\104.1~106.1\臺北捷運各站出站量統計_201501.csv",encoding='big5')
```

I can execute it before.I don't know why python happen OSError.

Is it could be my data which is Chinese?

I browsed a lot of question,but no one can't answer me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0dfa88abff19> in <module>()
----> 1 df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\champion\Desktop\政大資料科學競賽\104.1~106.1\臺北捷運各站出站量統計_201503.csv')

D:\anoconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    644                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    645 
--> 646         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    647 
    648     parser_f.__name__ = name

D:\anoconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    387 
    388     # Create the parser.
--> 389     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    390 
    391     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

D:\anoconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    728             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    729 
--> 730         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    731 
    732     def close(self):

D:\anoconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    921     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    922         if engine == 'c':
--> 923             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    924         else:
    925             if engine == 'python':

D:\anoconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1388         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1389 
-> 1390         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1391 
   1392         # XXX

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)()

pandas\parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8471)()



 OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

​
OSError: Initializing from file failed,is it mean my system is wrong?

Comment: Does the following command work: `open(r"C:\Users\champion\Desktop\政大資料科學競賽\104.1~106.1\臺北捷運各站出站量統計_201501.csv"`)`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256868/pandas-oserror-with-accent-special-character-in-file-path-and-file-name), this could be the same problem

Answer (score -1):

If u use python 3.6, u can try

> df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\champion\Desktop\政大資料科學競賽\104.1~106.1\臺北捷運各站出站量統計_201501.csv",encoding='big5',engine="python")