# pandas: oserror with accent/special character in file path and file name

Tags: python, csv, pandas, special-characters

I am trying to use `pandas.read_csv` to get data from some .csv files. This works fine as long as there is no accent (e.g. ä,é,ü) in the file name or file path. As soon as I use a file name such as `düm1.csv`I get the following error: `OSError: Initializing from file failed`. My code is:

`dum1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\dumm12\düm1.csv", sep = ";", decimal = ",", encoding = "utf-8")`

I am using pandas 0.20.1 and python 3.6.0. I have found that this has been an issue in previous versions but I thought it had been resolved. Any ideas on how to fix this? I also found this:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15086

output of pd.show_versions():

INSTALLED VERSIONS
commit: None
python: 3.6.0.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.20.1
pytest: 3.0.5
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: None
numpy: 1.11.3
scipy: 0.18.1
xarray: None
IPython: 5.2.2
sphinx: 1.5.1
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.0
pytz: 2016.10
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.6.2
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.0.0
openpyxl: 2.4.1
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
lxml: 3.7.3
bs4: 4.5.3
html5lib: 0.999
sqlalchemy: 1.1.5
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.5
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None

Comment: I can reproduce this error with Python 3.6.1, Pandas 0.20.1; however I did not have it until yesterday while working with Python 3.4.4 and Pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: That is weird. Might it be a bug in new versions and I should downgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It's look like the problem occurs with pandas.read_csv with Python 3.6 in a Windows system.

Python 3.6 change Windows filesystem encoding from "mbcs" to "UTF-8". See [Python PEP 529](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-529-change-windows-filesystem-encoding-to-utf-8). You can use the command `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` to get the current file system encoding

I get two solutions around this:

1.- Use this code to change all the app to works with the prior Python <= 3.5 encoding ("mbcs")

```
import sys
sys._enablelegacywindowsfsencoding()
```

2.- Pass a file pointer to the pandas.read_csv

```
with open("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\dumm12\düm1.csv", 'r') as fp:
        dum1 = pd.read_csv(fp, sep = ";", decimal = ",", encoding = "utf-8")
```

You can see this post: [pandas.read_csv can't import file with accent mark in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140297/pandas-read-csv-cant-import-file-with-accent-mark-in-path)

Answer (score 1):

I tested the name in creating a fake file 'düm1.csv'.

when I run :

```
df = pd.read_csv('düm1.csv',sep=';')
```

I haven't an OSError and the file is open in my Ipython.

```
   Unnamed: 0  test1  test2  test3  tes4
0         NaN    1.0    2.0    3.0   4.0
1         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
3         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
4         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Have you tried without encoding ? Without accent ?

C.

Comment: Thanks, it is weird that it works for you. I have tried without encoding but it does not work either. However, it works without accents. Any other ideas? Thank you for testing, this way I know it is not a general issue but rather related to my code, machine or package version.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm using python 3.6.1 and ipython 5.3.0. You can try with encoding='ISO-8859-1'

Comment: I tried with the encoding ISO-8859-1 but it did not work either. I will update python and ipython and hope it does help.

Comment: I tried with update python and ipython. It does not work with accents. It seems I have to live with the status quo.

Comment: Maybe it's depending of the language of your computer. I don't know, but if it you change the name and it's work finally you can use your data, the problem don't arise from your data or pandas. Good luck !

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I need to use files in a directory for which in can not change the name. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The  [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15086) hasn't been resolved till now. Wait till a PR. Or try it with Python 2.7 I guess that might work